# Are there nice inverse functions for the diagonal indexing function $x + (x + y) (1 + x + y) / 2$?

Tags: algorithms, inverse-function, triangular-numbers

I've been trying to work out nice inverse functions for the x and y coordinate parts of the diagonal indexing function
$$I(x,y) = x + \frac{(x + y) (1 + x + y)}{2},$$
which produces the table
$$\begin{array}{c|cccc}
  y \backslash x & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
  \hline
 0 & 0 &  2 &  5 &  9 & \\
 1 & 1 &  4 &  8 & 13 & \cdots\\
 2 & 3 &  7 & 12 & 18 \\
 3 & 6 & 11 & 17 & 24 \\
 && \vdots
\end{array}$$

I want two inverse functions, call them $K_x$ and $K_y$, which take the above numbers and reverse the transformation, for example $K_x(3) = 0$, $K_x(8) = 2$, $K_y(8) = 1$.

I have come up with some which work, but they are not very nice functions. Let
$$T(k) = k (k + 1)/2 \qquad (\text{the triangular numbers}) \\
  T^{-1}_f(k) = \left\lfloor \frac{\sqrt{1 + 8 k} - 1}{2} \right\rfloor \\
  T^{-1}_c(k) = \left\lceil \frac{\sqrt{1 + 8 k} - 1}{2} \right\rceil$$
then
$$K_x(k) = k - T(T^{-1}_f(k)) \\
  K_y(k) = T(T^{-1}_c(k + 1)) - k - 1.$$

Now, these functions work, but I find them somewhat ugly. We want to find which triangular number are below and above our number. We do this by taking the inverse triangular number, which requires a square root, which comes out as an algebraic number when the input isn't triangular, so then we need to floor/ceiling.

My question is: is there a better way than this?

The solution doesn't have to be a closed form expression; an algorithm would be great (so long as it's more efficient than "try all the numbers in range"). But if they are nice, meaningful closed form expressions, then all the better.

Comment: I think the solution is already quite effective

Comment: For an algorithm: maybe to find the binary form of the inverse function to $T$, start out with roughly $2^{d/2}$ or $2^{d/2+1}$ where $d$ is the number of digits of the input.  Then for each place $2^k$ for $k$ decreasing, try adding that to the accumulator and see if the value of $T$ still falls below your desired output; if not, revert to the previous accumulator.  You could probably even optimize a bit by precomputing $\frac{a(a+1)}{2}$ where $a$ is the current accumulator, and see how to simplify calculating $\frac{(a+2^k)(a+2^k+1)}{2}$ based on that.

Comment: Is the formula for $K_y$ right? $T_f^{-1}(k)$ is the index of the diagonal that $k$ appears on, so you should have $K_x(k) + K_y(k) = T_f^{-1}(k)$

Comment: The formula for $K_y$ seems to work when I run it. The idea is that the ceiling will give you the triangular number one above the value you want; this doesn't work when it's an integer triangular number, hence the +1. However, you're quite right that $K_y(k) = T^{-1}_f(k) - K_x(k)$, and I think that's much nicer than using both the floor and ceiling.

Comment: I've come across the [integer square root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_square_root), which seems relevant. Similar to @DanielSchepler's point above, it appears you can do a search in the range $(1+8k)^2 {..{<}} (2+8k)^2$.

Comment: You should calculate $T_c^{-1}(1)=1$ and by your formula $K_y(1)=-1$. Be careful when doing calculations with floating point numbers. There will be round off error which makes ceiling/floor unreliable. In an algorithm you should check if it's exactly a triangular number first.